# Restoring Emulator Data

Tags: emulation

Is it possible to restore the emulator data (save data) from a previous emulator on to a new emulator for a game like for example "Pokemon Crystal" if you have the files on an Iphone 6 ? Thank you.

Note : I have purchased a "Gameboy Color" and a physical copy of the specific game in the past.

Specific emuluator and install instructions link: http://iphonecydiaios.com/install-gameboy-color-emulator-without-jailbreak-ios-8-2-and-8-3/

Comment: I have trouble to understand your question. Are you asking whether it is possible to copy the game state from the emulator into a game cartridge? In that case, the answer is most likely yes if you have the a appropriate hardware.

Comment: What exactly does "restore emulator data" mean? Are you talking about save game files for the game? Configuration files for the emulator itself? Save states? If you already have the files, then what do you need to restore exactly? Does your emulator not know where the files are? Which emulator are you talking about in the first place? As it is now, the question is unclear and not answerable. Please edit it.

Comment: @Nolonar would this be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Every Gameboy emulator uses `.sav` files to store the game data.

You should be able to find those files somewhere on your device, and use them with another emulator. They are usually located in the same folder as the ROM (`.gb` or `.zip` file).

Comment: Yes i have the .zip files the problem in getting them to work in the emulator, are there any particular steps I must go through in order to attach the files to the emulator?

Comment: the .zip file is not the save (generally), it's the ROM itself. @Ealhad was just saying that they're normally located in the same place. The file you want should end with ".sav".

Comment: @Amadeus9 o ok i get it now, thank you ,but i did back it up and have all necessary files (.sav .zip etc...) i just don't know how to enable them on to the new emulator

Comment: @Adam.A Again, if they are in the same folder as the ROM, they should be used automatically. If not, your emulator should have a specific folder for save files, and you should put them there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have as you said only a .zip file, I can talk from my experience here:

It depends on the Emulator, but it usually saves them in the direct folder of the game, a seperate folder for the Emulator or rarely, and I have also encountered that on the Phone, in a sort of binary addition directly to the game file or the zip, making the save effectively unreadable by other emulators. I don't know why programmers do this, but if that is the case you can pretty much forget converting your safe if the Emulator doesn't provide a feature for that.

But you should of course try the other options first, just don't ask yourself desperately why you can't find anything, since this is also a possibility